# Apply same handler to multiple jQuery objects

Tags: javascript, jquery

I know I can use `$.each` to apply the same event handler to two different jQuery objects. I'm surprised it was not possible to have a cleaner syntax such as:

```
  var $span = $('span');
  var $div = $('div');

  var clickHandler = function () {
    $(this).toggleClass('red');
  }

  $($span, $div).on('click', clickHandler); // <-- Neater syntax
  $([$span, $div]).on('click', clickHandler); // <-- A little worse, but still better than $.each
```

Why do the syntaxes I have tried not work? Is there a neater alternative to using `$.each`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$span.add($div).on('click', clickHandler)
```

Should do what you want, per the [`add()` docs](http://api.jquery.com/add).

1. `$($span, $div)` is being interpreted as `$span`'s which are descendants of `$div`.
2. `$([$span, $div])` expects the array elements to be `DOMElements`, not jQuery objects (I've always wished this was possible as well)

You can see both of these syntaxs described in the [jQuery documentation](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery)

Answer (score 2):

You can use CSS syntax for multiple selectors - the comma `,`:

```
$('span, div').on('click', clickHandler);
```

Or if you have variables containing the elements, you can use `add()`

```
$span.add($div).on('click', clickHandler);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also use jQuery's [`.add()`<sup>link</sup>](http://api.jquery.com/add/) method to *extend* a wrapped set

```
$span.add( $div ).on( 'click', clickHandler );
```